# How to make the server responds with a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to finish Assignment 7 from CS106A (http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/assn/bajillion) and I'm stuck on Part C.

I built up the index and search function in one file and want to call it from another. My index function takes in parameters:

```
filenames:      a list of file names (strings)

index:          a dictionary mapping from terms to file names (i.e., inverted index)
                (term -> list of file names that contain that term)

file_titles:    a dictionary mapping from a file names to the title of the article
                in a given file
                (file name -> title of article in that file)
```

and updates the index.

My search function takes in the index and a query and returns a list of the names of all the files that contain all of the terms in the query (using the index passed in).

In another file I have my Server (the code is provided by Stanford):

```
# the directory of files to search over
DIRECTORY = 'bbcnews'
# perhaps you want to limit to only 10 responses per search..
MAX_RESPONSES_PER_REQUEST = 10

class SearchServer:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        load the data that we need to run the search engine. This happens
        once when the server is first created.
        """
        self.html = open('extension_client.html').read()

        # TODO: Your code here. Change this code to load any data you want to use!**

    # this is the server request callback function. You can't change its name or params!!!
    def handle_request(self, request):
        """
        This function gets called every time someone makes a request to our
        server. To handle a search, look for the query parameter with key "query"
        """
        # it is helpful to print out each request you receive!
        print(request)

        # if the command is empty, return the html for the search page
        if request.command == '':
            return self.html

        # if the command is search, the client wants you to perform a search!
        if request.command == 'search':
            # right now we respond to a search request with an empty string.
            # TODO: Your code here. change this code to return the string version 
            # of a list of dicts. Use json.dumps(collection) to turn a list into a string**
            return ''


def main():
    # make an instance of your Server
    handler = SearchServer()
    # start the server to handle internet requests!
    SimpleServer.run_server(handler, 8000) # make the server
```

I don't understand how to load the data into the class SearchServer and how to search.
I have tried:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.html = open('extension_client.html').read()

    self.idx = create_index()
    self.titles = create_index()
```

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, I'd just like to highlight the honor code for this class: Rule 1: You must not look at solutions or program code that are not your own. Rule 3: You must indicate on your submission any assistance you received. Note: ... we strongly encourage
you to seek such assistance when you need it. Discuss ideas together, but do the coding
on your own. [Source](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/handouts/03-honor-code.pdf)

Comment: Thank for your comments. It's not my homework. I'm 30 years old and trying to learn OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating the index in the `__init__` method:

```
class SearchServer:
    def __init__(self, data_dir="bbcnews"):
        """
        load the data that we need to run the search engine. This happens
        once when the server is first created.
        """
        self.html = open('extension_client.html').read()

        self.index = {}
        self.file_titles = {}
        create_index(textfiles_in_dir(data_dir), self.index, self.file_titles)
```

I added an extra optional parameter `data_dir` so that you could choose `"small"` instead if you wanted, like this:

```
handler = SearchServer("small")
```

In the `handle_request` method, I created the required json object as such:

```
json.dumps([{"title": self.file_titles[filename]} for filename in search(self.index, request.params["query"])])
```

---

### My whole code:

```
# this imports the SimpleServer library
import SimpleServer
# This imports the functions you defined in searchengine.py
from searchengine import create_index, search, textfiles_in_dir
# has the json.dumps function. So useful
import json

"""
File: extension_server.py
---------------------
This starts a server! Go to http://localhost:8000 to enjoy it. Currently
the server only serves up the HTML. It does not search. Implement code in
the TODO parts of this file to make it work.
"""

# the directory of files to search over
DIRECTORY = 'bbcnews'
# perhaps you want to limit to only 10 responses per search..
MAX_RESPONSES_PER_REQUEST = 10

class SearchServer:
    def __init__(self, data_dir="bbcnews"):
        """
        load the data that we need to run the search engine. This happens
        once when the server is first created.
        """
        self.html = open('extension_client.html').read()

        self.index = {}
        self.file_titles = {}
        create_index(textfiles_in_dir(data_dir), self.index, self.file_titles)


    # this is the server request callback function. You can't change its name or params!!!
    def handle_request(self, request):
        """
        This function gets called every time someone makes a request to our
        server. To handle a search, look for the query parameter with key "query"
        """
        # it is helpful to print out each request you receive!
        print(request)

        # if the command is empty, return the html for the search page
        if request.command == '':
            return self.html

        # if the command is search, the client wants you to perform a search!
        if request.command == 'search':
            # right now we respond to a search request with an empty string.
            # TODO: Your code here. change this code to return the string version 
            # of a list of dicts. Use json.dumps(collection) to turn a list into a string

            
            return json.dumps([{"title": self.file_titles[filename]} for filename in search(self.index, request.params["query"])])


def main():
    # make an instance of your Server
    handler = SearchServer()
    # start the server to handle internet requests!
    SimpleServer.run_server(handler, 8000) # make the server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

### An explanation

I don't know how familiar you are with generator expressions and list comprehensions, so I'll try to explain anyway.

---

This line is an example of a list comprehension in Python:

```
[{"title": self.file_titles[filename]} for filename in search(self.index, request.params["query"])]
```

If we look at the iteration, we can see we loop through each filename that is returned by our `search` function:

```
for filename in search(self.index, request.params["query"])]
```

`request.params["query"]` simply means "get the `?query=xxx` bit from the url".

And for each filename, we construct this dictionary:

```
{"title": self.file_titles[filename]}
```

And the `[]` around the whole thing tells Python that we want it to be a list.

---

It's roughly equivalent to this:

```
lst = []
for filename in search(self.index, request.params["query"]):
    dct = {"title": self.file_titles[filename]}
    lst.append(lst)
```

---

Comment: Thank you @Ed ! Trying to add url and snippet to the dictionary. Would it be something like:             `return json.dumps([{"title": urllib.parse(self.file_titles[filename], urllib.request.pathname2url("DIRECTORY/filename")), "snippet": (open(filename)).readlines()[2]} for filename in search(self.index, request.params["query"])], indent=2)`
 So it shows the result as: the url to the document as the title name and a snippet of the article from the DIRECTORY

Comment: I think that would work... If you wanted to go even further, you could use an HTML template and populate it with the results from the search :)